# Can you set a QGIS print composer to render the map as default?

Tags: qgis, rendering, cache, printing, print-composer

I have set up a number of templates for the print composer in QGIS.

In the Print Composer, there is the option to have the map image displayed in 3 ways:

- as a blank rectangle with no updates until it is output
- as a manual refresh based on cache
- as a rendered refresh

When my templates are opened, the map image loads as a blank rectangle by defualt, is there a way either in QGIS settings or in the template itself to force the map image to load as "Cache" or "Render" without having to manually change this?

Comment: This is rectified in QGIS v2 onwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QGIS V2 onwards solves this. The question was submitted using QGIS 1.8